# grouped dataframe - groupings as facets in a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Some data

```
grp_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>%
  group_split


grp_diamonds[[1]] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point()
```

This returns a plot for `grp_diamonds[[1]]`
[image]

But grp_diamonds is actually a list of 5 dataframes since I used `group_split()` earlier.

Is there a clever way to automatically use the groups as facets?

Yes, in this example you could just do this:

```
diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cut))
```

But I wondered if there was a way to automatically facet based on existing groupings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `dplyr::groups` and `dplyr::vars` and `!!!`one option would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

grp_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color)

grp_diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(!!!groups(grp_diamonds)))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I was optimistic there would be an elegant approach like this. Thank you